# linq query with or and operator together

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I need to run multiple conditions in linq query with or, and operator. First I need to compare with three conditions, which are separated by || operator, once one of the conditions is true I also need to see if check is true which I using && operator but I got all the result

so for example from following query, if ModuleLead == ContextSession.StaffID then record must have ClinicalSupervisorCheck == true

```
var query_b = (from b in activeAssessmentWithRemidiation
                where b.AssessorID == ContextSession.StaffID 
                   || b.ModuleLead == ContextSession.StaffID 
                   && b.ClinicalSupervisorCheck == true 
                   || b.SeniorStaffID == ContextSession.StaffID 
                   && b.ModuleLeadCheck==true
                   select b).ToList();
```

the above query is running on following table records

[image]

Comment: You should use parenthesis to group criteria.   `(a || b) && c` is different than `a || b && c`

Comment: What is the result you get, and what is the result you would expect instead?

Comment: The image doesn't show AssessorID, StaffID or ModuleLead. Which ID corresponds to which column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be worth wrapping the AND conditions in parathensis, for example:

```
    var query_b = (from b in activeAssessmentWithRemidiation
                   where b.AssessorID == ContextSession.StaffID || 
                  (b.ModuleLead == ContextSession.StaffID && b.ClinicalSupervisorCheck == true) ||
                  (b.SeniorStaffID == ContextSession.StaffID && b.ModuleLeadCheck==true)
                   select b).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

proper use of `(`  and `)`

```
var query_b = (from b in activeAssessmentWithRemidiation
            where (((b.AssessorID == ContextSession.StaffID 
               || b.ModuleLead == ContextSession.StaffID )
               && b.ClinicalSupervisorCheck == true)
               ||
               (b.SeniorStaffID == ContextSession.StaffID 
               && b.ModuleLeadCheck==true))
               select b).ToList();
```

Comment: @Jamiec it was typo.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis for that. Remember that operator && will be tested before || operators if you don't use parenthesis.